# Google Firebase Analytics With Android

Tags: android, analytics, firebase-analytics

I am trying to implement Google Firebase analytics in very small application having 2 or 3 Activity.

how can i start ?
Any reference application for first App using Firebase Analytics?

please suggest online course for the same.

Comment: Hi, you can follow the official guide from Google https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=android

Answer (score 0):

Please check step by step process from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=android).

Comment: Thanks. Its working fine. Is there any online course available so that i can implement on project.